# how to chat window to display the selected value after the user clicks the button in the botframework chatbot?

Tags: python, performance, botframework

In the python botchat(Webchat),

I want chat Window to display the selected value after the user clicks the button?

**And I want to code in this thing in the Client Side , please help me**

Also, I want to know about how to use `ActionTypes.im_back`.

chat window to display the selected value after the user clicks the button.

```
if str(context.activity.value) != 'None':
 response = context.activity.value  #json ex:{'value':'hello'}
 # if i do,  prompt_message = await 
 create_reply_activity(context.activity, respone.get('value'))
 # bot will say what user typed. but i want to make it from client side like what i could see in
 # contososcubademo.azurewebsites.net
 prompt_message = await create_reply_activity(context.activity, answer)
 gen_result=await oneday_hanlde.Input_generator(response,state.Flow)
 answer= gen_result[0] #text ex: 'hi there!'
 prompt_message = await create_reply_activity(context.activity, answer)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What is "the button?"  What is "the selected value"?  This is not nearly enough information for you to expect any kind of real answer here.  Please take some time to learn [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You'll get much better results if you put more effort into asking your question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm assuming you are using Adaptive Cards since you mention buttons.
There are a handful of actions you can define for your button and that selection will determine how things are viewed by the bot users and other users, if in a group chat like Teams.
You can learn more detail here: [Adaptive Card Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-actions)

openUrl: Opens the specified URL in a new browser window. Useful for downloading files or to direct users to other websites.
messageBack: Sends a message and payload (Value property), to the bot, and sends a separate message top the chat stream. This is probably what you want to use to show the selected value back to the users in reference to your first ask.
imBack: Similar to messageBack except this question and the value displayed will be visible to all user in the conversation
invoke: Sends a message and payload to the bot. Nothing is visible to the user
signin: Starts the OAuth flow

Please note, not all channels support all Action (even if that channel supports Adaptive Cards)

Comment: Thank you for your reply , so  I just apply your reference , msteams{'type':'imback", "value":"type"} but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hrmm, I'm going to try and duplicate a little later today since what you have 'should' give you a result. Basically, 'type' should be sent to the bot and echo'd in the chat window. It's possible there is an issue in the python bot code or even something in the webchat. Are you using the latest webchat?

Comment: Hello,  I just use insert below code on card. "msteams":{"type":"imback", "value":"Text to reply in chat"}. And I will check the latest version for webchat.  your answer is so helpful for me, Thanks again :)

Comment: Hello, But I just want to set here as Client Side.  Not in the bot side. Thank you